# How to use Shared Preferences?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am new to android..and I'm developing an application using Json. I want to pass a string value from my main activity to another class without starting the activity class. I heard there is some way using shared preferences. I just tried.. but didn't worked..i got null point exception.. here is my code...

```
confirm = check.AuthenticateUser(name, passwd);  
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putString("Name",confirm);
editor.commit();
```

here is the place i want to send the value of "confirm" (string variable)

and below code shows where i want to get that preference..actually that class named "ShortList".

here is the code where i trying to get the value

```
public class ShortList extends Activity  {

//ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arl;

  SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
  String cargivr = preferences.getString("Name","");
```

please some one help me..

Comment: make sure you are initializing `preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);` inside method like in onCreate or onResume inside in class?

Comment: is this part of code is inside annonymus inner class

Comment: cant i use shared preferences in a normal class ?

Comment: as long as u can get contex(Activity/service/broadcast) u can use in any class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class ShortList extends Activity  {

//ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arl;

  SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
  String cargivr = preferences.getString("Name","");
```

Here it seems you're initializing member variables.

You cannot use an `Activity` as a `Context` until `onCreate()` in the activity lifecycle. Member variable initialization is too early and will usually lead to NPE in `getBaseContext()`.

Move the initialization of `preferences` and `cargivr` to `onCreate()` or later.

Comment: i have done this.. but for the value of caregiver i get null value...can you tell me why ?

Comment: @user3020939 Not really with the information available. Maybe you didn't put a non-empty value in the first place or you're trying to access the value before it has been put there.

Comment: both codes i have put inside of oncreate methods...but i have hard coded the putString("dv","xxx");   like this...but itz not working

Answer (score 1):

```
public static String CREDENTIALS_FILENAME = "com.myapp.credentials";
public static String PIN = "pin";

public static void writeCredentials(Context c,String pin) {

        SharedPreferences credentialsPref = c.getSharedPreferences(CREDENTIALS_FILENAME, 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = credentialsPref.edit();
        editor.putString(PIN, pin);
        editor.commit();

    }

public static String readCredentials(Context c,String pin) {

        SharedPreferences credentialsPref = c.getSharedPreferences(CREDENTIALS_FILENAME, 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = credentialsPref.edit();
        return credentialsPref.getString(PIN, "default value"); 

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

MainActivity.java

```
SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("New",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor edit = pref.edit();
edit.putString("SomeKey", "SomeValue");
edit.commit();
```

SecondActivity.java

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("New",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String value = prefs.getString("SomeKey","DefaultValue");
```

Also make sure that you have added the second activity details in your android manifest file -

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.projectName.SecondActivity"
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.sharedpref.MainActivity">        
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ShortList.this);
String cargivr = preferences.getString("Name","");
```